# Create image with sum of column

Tags: php, mysql

Can somebody explain how to create image with number, that i am getting with this query:

```
$sumq = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(count) FROM downloads");
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($sumq);
```

Comment: take your pick: http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: Can you explain the motive for displaying an image instead of text/html ?

Comment: its needed for my university work at the end of the year, where i ll need to generate number with sum of 1 column and showing it on another web-page without connect to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [imagestring](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagestring.php) :

```
<?php
$text = 42; // whatever your number is

// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $text, $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```